# Show original image for selected UITabBarItem (storyboard) iOS10

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using UITabBarController with 5 ViewController each ViewController have own UINavigationController as below:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

I have added tabar image like

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

As seen from above image when TabBarItem is selected just blue image i can see...i wanted to show original image for selected tabaritem.

I had seen the example of setting property UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal. but i can not see anything on story board.

Below is the way I push TabBarController:

```
HomeViewController *vcHome = (HomeViewController*)[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"NexTabBar" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ID_HOME_VC"];
vcHome.delegate = self;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vcHome animated:YES];
```

How can I use the property UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal here so that I can see original images when particular TabBarItem is selected?

or if any other way is there with ios10.

Comment: your first image is too blur, can you provide a  high-resolution one?

Comment: it is just UITabBarController in StoryBoard....with five TabBarItem....the basic controller i could only take out screen shorts....

Comment: there is property UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal but i do not know how to use in my case..when we load UITabBarController from storyboard... and not programmatically...

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I create tabBarItem for myTabBar

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboardIdentifier, bundle: nil)
    let vc:UIViewController? = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController();
    let selectedImage = UIImage(named: imageName)
    let notSelectedImage = UIImage(named:selectedImageName)?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    let item = UITabBarItem(title: title, image: notSelectedImage, selectedImage: selectedImage)
    vc!.tabBarItem = item
```

Objective C version:

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardIdentifier bundle:nil];
UIViewController* vc = sb.instantiateInitialViewController;
UIImage* selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:image] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
UIImage* notSelectedimage = [[UIImage imageNamed:selectedImageName] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
UITabBarItem* item = [[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTitle:title image:notSelectedimage selectedImage:selectedImage];
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
vc.tabBarItem = item;
return vc;
```

If this did not help try to change also tabBar tints colors

```
    self.tabBar.barTintColor = .orange

    // set color of selected icons and text to white
    self.tabBar.tintColor = .white
    UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white], for: .selected)


    // set color of unselected text to gray
    UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.gray], for: .normal)
```

Comment: i tried but it has only changed unselected color to white, as setSelectedImageTintColor not available i had addedsetUnselectedItemTintColor.     when images are selected it still showing blue default image... :(